# POSIX reg. exp to test the divisibility by 9

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression

Write the shortest POSIX-form regular expression that matches only non-negative integers divisible by 9. The non-negative integer should be given in base 10.

Comment: Is this too similar to the regex challenge to check divisibility by 7? I am inclined to think yes, but I am not going to flag it.

Comment: You can do it just [like you do for 3](http://quaxio.com/triple/). 9 has a similar rule; any integer divisible by 9 has digits summing to another multiple of 9. It makes the state machine more complex, but the same principle applies.

Comment: Are there a free Linux program to make the conversion from finite state machine to reg. exp.?

Comment: this seem to be a bit code-bowling...

Answer (score 1):

## 202,071 bytes

Obviously, [the solution](https://gist.github.com/nhahtdh/9405617#file-divisibleby9-re) is too large to be included in this post.

I use [JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/) to draw the [DFA](https://gist.github.com/nhahtdh/9405617#file-g23235-jff), then generate regex from it. The output is then processed in a text editor to replace `(0+9)` with `[09]` and `+` with `|`.

[Here is the whole gist](https://gist.github.com/nhahtdh/9405617), with some testing code in Java.